# Independent Domain Layer

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

If you are using NHibernate is it possible to make class declarations independent from such a thing like `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<>`?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends whether a child collection needs to implement `ISet` as to whether you need to use it, in much the same way as a child collection may implement `IEnumerable` or any other interface :) NHibernate used the collections in `Iesi.Collections` before similar collections were introduced into the .NET framework

Comment: I'm asking because of the next thing. I looked at `Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns` where most things incredibly described. Especially I mentioned Chapter 7 explanation! Within one solution author makes it flexible to use different implementations of `DataAccessLayer`. But model he uses doesn't contain a reference to `Iesi` collections so its like kind of 'clean'.. I want to use a NHibernate repository implementation though. And I don't know should I keep contracts like `IUnitOfWorkRepository` and `IUnitOfWork` and related things or not?

Comment: I think the problem with taking a "swapping in and out DataAccessLayer implementations" approach e.g. some kind of Repository pattern, is that it forces the layer to only being able to adopt the lowest common denominator of functionality and does not lend itself well to advanced features available in mature ORMs like NHibernate and Entity Framework such as various fetching and loading strategies. Indeed, in my experience at least, it's rare that a DataAccessLayer is replaced with another complete implementation. BTW, do you have a page reference for ASP.NET Design patterns?

Comment: If you mean printable version then it starts from 196th page, chapter 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part you can have your classes expose collections as ICollection< T >.  Remember to initialize them in your constructor though.

Comment: So will NHibernate map `ICollection<T>` to `set` construction normally?

Comment: Yes per ayende: 
http://ayende.com/blog/3971/nhibernate-tidbit-using-set-without-referencing-iesi-collections